# How to solve CORS problem on requests on angular?

Tags: angular

Description

I'm trying to make a POST request like this :

```
return this.http.post("http://192.168.28.88:6010/api"+ '/login', user);
```

I got this error on my browser :

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://192.168.88.28:6010/api/login' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

**Note:** I tried to solution about proxyConfig but not working.

Need your helps

Comment: Remember that CORS policies are configured by the server, not the client.  The server gets to determine who can make cross-origin requests.  You will need to mention what web server you are running.

Comment: Yes the server is well configured :                                                                                                   Set-PodeSecurityAccessControl -Origin ' * ' -Methods ' * ' -Headers ' * ' -Duration 7200

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a HTTP Header

```
httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    })
  }

return this.http.post("http://192.168.28.88:6010/api"+ '/login', user, this.httpOptions);
```

Comment: The server is free to ignore anything sent from the client with regards to CORS policies.  It's in control.  This won't help.

Comment: Yes the server is well configured : Set-PodeSecurityAccessControl -Origin ' * ' -Methods ' * ' -Headers ' * ' -Duration 7200